# remove() function for list not working

Tags: python

I have written a python script to calculate semantic similarity between words in a set. Based on that I want to remove words that are not strongly correlated to others. Following is the code for removing a word from the set.

```
line_combined=copy(line1)
threshold = 1/len(line_combined)
for word3 in line_combined:
    print("simdict[" + word3 + "] =" + str(simdict[word3]))
    print ("ratio is: " + str(simdict[word3]/linesumsim))
    if(simdict[word3]/linesumsim)<threshold:
        line_combined.remove(word3)
        print word3 + " is removed"
print "the output is:"
print line_combined
```

"line1" is the set of words under consideration, used as list. "simdict[word]" holds the sum of similarities of "word" with rest of the words in the set. "linesumsim" is the sum of all "simdict" value for all the words in the set.

Output is:

```
linesumsim is 2.82012427883
simdict[city] =0.517357507497
ratio is: 0.183452024217
simdict[mountain] =0.642265108364
ratio is: 0.227743547752
simdict[sky] =0.484908130427
ratio is: 0.171945660007
simdict[sun] =0.637289239227
ratio is: 0.225979132909
simdict[characteristics] =0.538304293319
ratio is: 0.190879635114
the output is:
['city', 'mountain', 'sky', 'sun', 'characteristics']
```

Clearly there are words with simdict value less that threshold, 0.2 in this case. But they are not getting removed

Comment: a guess, but threshold = 1.0 / len(line_combined). Integer division as in 1/ 5 = 0 I think

Comment: @TonyHopkinson : true, I changed thershold = float(1)/len(line_combined). It works. Thanks for pointing out! Also i had to change the for loop as limelights pointed out

Comment: @nish 1.0 is shorter than float(1)... and for similiar cases: Never trust any assumptions you make. A `print "threshold is", threshold` at the beginning would have been helpful as well.

Comment: and besides, the title is wrong. If `remove()` would have been the problem, you had lines like `sky is removed` which would prove not to be true. As you don't have such lines, the problem lies more "outside" (i. e., probably in the `if` condition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove while iterating over the same list you want to remove from.

Change

```
for word3 in line_combined:
```

to

```
for word3 in line1:
```

Comment: I have doubt, how following code working, its removing the item, plz correct me if something is wrong. 

a = [1,2,3,4]

for i in a:

   if a.index(i) == 2:

      a.remove(i)


print a